# Jetpack Animation for two composables

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, android-jetpack-compose

I am relatively new to jetpack compose.  I would like some suggestions for a task. Task include

The task steps are

1. Show logo of application by scale in animation
2. Logo should disappear with scale out animation
3. Once logo disappear login screen should appear by scale in animation

I want to acheive this thorugh android animations. I looked for crossfade and animated content but the issue is no way i can find out that logo is scaled out from enter exit transition so after logo is scaled out then only i want login screen to scale in.
If anyone can suggest anyway to achieve this.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you explain the task in more detail? Preferably an algorithm for the desired animation step by step.
I will edit this message if i can help, or more details from you will help for other respondents.

UPDATE

Like this?

[AnimatedScreenAndLogo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyHz3.gif)

UPDATE 2

Function for animate content by scale:

```
@Composable
private fun ScaleAnimatedVisibility(
    visible: Boolean,
    scalePosition: (scale: Float) -> Unit,
    animationDurationMillis: Int,
    delayScaleInAnimation: Int = 0,
    delayScaleOutAnimation: Int = 0,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val scale by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (visible) 1f else 0f,
        animationSpec = tween(
            delayMillis = if (visible) delayScaleInAnimation else delayScaleOutAnimation,
            durationMillis = animationDurationMillis
        ),
        label = ""
    )

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.scale(scale = scale)
    ) {
        scalePosition(scale)
        content()
    }
}
```

Example of use:

```
@Composable
fun AnimatedScreenAndLogo() {
    var animationIsPlaying by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    var animateLogo by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var animateLoginScreen by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(color = Color.White),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        ScaleAnimatedVisibility(
            visible = animateLogo,
            scalePosition = { scale ->
                if (animateLogo && animationIsPlaying && scale == 1f) {
                    animateLogo = false
                } else {
                    if (!animateLogo && animationIsPlaying && scale == 0f) {
                        animateLoginScreen = true
                    }
                }
            },
            delayScaleOutAnimation = 1000,
            animationDurationMillis = 1000
        ) {
            Logo()
        }

        ScaleAnimatedVisibility(
            visible = animateLoginScreen,
            scalePosition = {},
            animationDurationMillis = 1000,
            delayScaleInAnimation = 1000,
        ) {
            LoginScreen()
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = {
        animationIsPlaying = true
        animateLogo = true
    })
}
```

Comment: The task steps are 1. Show logo of application by scale in animation 2. Logo should disappear with scale out animation  3. Once logo disappear login screen should appear by scale in animation

Comment: @zzz I have attached a demo in the post above, do you want the same animation effect?

Comment: Yes sir exactly like this

Comment: @zzz I have added a code in the post above)